# Store unsigned short inside a char*?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

Here is my following code, in my for loop I'm trying to store an unsigned short int inside of the char* memory created by malloc. I'm indexing to do this and I would like to keep it that way if possible.

However, inside myMemory when printing out a sizeof(myMemory[0]) or even printing out the address myMemory[0] itself, it seems that the integer value of p is being stored, not the unsigned short int. The integer itself is correct, but the byte size is 1, not 2, hence not an unsigned short int.

```
char* myMemory;
typedef unsigned short int R;
void main(){
R *p:
myMemory = malloc(65536)

for (int i = 0; i<36;i++){
    myMemory[i] = p;
    i++;
    myMemory[i] = p;
    p++;
    p++;
}
printf("testing size of an index %d\n",sizeof(myMemory[2]));
```

}

Comment: I think you are looking for a `union { char value[sizeof(unsigned short int)], unsigned short int p; }` Then you can store an unsigned short int into p and read its bytes via char* values

Comment: You are storing the value of an `unsigned short int*` pointer value inside a `char` variable `myMemory[i] = p`. Please read compiler warnings. You are _not_ storing `unsigned short` value inside `char *` variable. `The integer itself is correct, but the byte size is 1, not 2, hence not an unsigned short int.` - how do you check that? Can you post reproducible example with ex. `printf` and the output you get and the output you expected to see?

Comment: @KamilCuk code has been updated with the print statement I am using to see if the myMemory index is an integer or an unsigned short int. I believe my problem has something to do with casting, or not using pointers correctly. Sorry i forgot to include the actual printf statement result but it is this "testing size of an index 1" while it should be "testing size of an index 2" as I want the char array to hold an unsigned short int

Comment: `sizeof(myMemory[2])` is `sizeof(*(char*)` is `sizeof(char)` which is by definition always `1`. `index 2` - then print the index `2` not `sizeof()` from an element. `char` has 8 bits, `unsigned short int` probably has 16 bits, how do you want to store the `short int` inside `char` array? Big endian? Little endian?

Comment: @KamilCuk Updated my previous comment, but I see what you are saying now. Is it possible that I need to make a print statement that points to the object the index is holding? I am sorry, I'm fairly new to C and the usage of stackoverflow.

Comment: `R *p` - p is a _pointer_ to `unsigned short int` element (and is uninitialized, which is bad). Then you do `myMemory[i] = p`. This takes 8 bits from the _pointer value_ whatever it is, as the pointer is uninitialized, so the pointer value is "indeterminate". Probably `sizeof(p)` is 4 or 8, so you are ignoring some bytes. If you want to store `unsigned short int` inside `char` array, you probably aim at something like this: `unsigned char int one = 1; myMemory[0] = one; myMemory[1] = (one >> 8);` (or `R one = 1`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
char* myMemory = malloc(sizeof(*p) * 36);
for (int i=0; i<36; ++i) {
    memcpy(myMemory+i, p, sizeof(*p));
    i += sizeof(*p);
    ++p;
}
```

But you could simply use

```
char* myMemory = malloc(sizeof(*p) * 36);
memcpy(myMemory, p, sizeof(*p) * 36);
p += 36;
```

Note that incrementing a pointer causes it to move forward to the next element, so `++p` advanced the pointer by `sizeof(*p)` bytes, and `p += 36` advances it by `sizeof(*p) * 36` bytes.